# Function returning varchar2 gives wrong result

Tags: oracle, where-clause, dynamic-sql

I want to build query dynamically as per criterias selected from gui. Here is my oracle package,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TestPkg 
AS
    g_lastnamelist VARCHAR2(50);

    FUNCTION getLastName return VARCHAR2;
    FUNCTION buildQuery(p_lastnamelist VARCHAR2);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TestPkg 
AS

   FUNCTION getLastName return VARCHAR2
   IS
   BEGIN
       RETURN replace(g_lastnamelist, '''', '');
   END;

   FUNCTION buildQuery(p_lastnamelist VARCHAR2);
   IS
       m_query varchar2(1000);
   BEGIN
       g_lastnamelist := p_lastnamelist;
       m_query := 'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE last_name IN(TestPkg.getLastName)';
   END;
END;
```

here if i use `'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE last_name IN('||p_lastnamelist||')';` then it returns me correct record but if i use `'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE last_name IN(TestPkg.getLastName)';` like this, then it fails. Whats the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're passing in a comma-separated list of quoted values, for example `p_lastnamelist` is `'Smith','Jones'`, as that's the only way your first query will work, and explains the `replace` call. (It helps if you show the input, output and any errors you get, so we don't have to guess and assume). When that's used in the queries they end up looking significantly different. The first one:

```
'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE last_name IN('||p_lastnamelist||')'
```

becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE last_name IN('Smith','Jones')
```

... which will match on any records with either of those last names. But the second one:

```
'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE last_name IN(TestPkg.getLastName)'
```

becomes, after you've stripped the quotes from the *value*:

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE last_name IN('Smith,Jones')
```

... which is looking for a single value, and would only match if you had a record with last name `Smith,Jones`, which is unlikely. Whatever is returned by `TestPkg.getLastName` will be treated a single string value. It has to be since the function returns a `varchar2`. But that's also the case if you use a bind variable as Egor suggested.

Comment: Yes I understood the problem, now I am returning StringList from getLastName function and using query SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(TestPkg.getLastName).

Comment: @eatSleepCode - great, I'll stop looking for an example of how to do that *8-)